Cannot add a primary key to a table
I am trying to add a primary key to a table using this script:
USE [C01]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CHECKREGISTER] 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TRANSACTIONID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
                      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                      ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

But when I try, I get the following error:

Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.CHECKREGISTER' and the index name'PK__CHECKREG__356DA90E668030F6'. The duplicate key value is (0). >
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
Could not create constraint. See previous errors. The statement has been terminated.

But when I look in the database 'tree', it shows no keys or constraints. What should I do?

I believe the error message is telling you that you already have duplicate records in the table - so it can’t create an index/key that requires there not to be duplicates

What about the error message is unclear? The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found means there are duplicates in your TRANSACTIONID key column so it can't create it.

The error message also calls out the duplicate key value (zero). You can see the problem rows with SELECT * FROM dbo.CHECKREGISTER WHERE TRANSACTIONID = 0;

You have set IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF. The message is telling you that you have a duplicate key. Check that table again. You might have missed the primary key. If you really think that's not the case set IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON.

If you're adding a primary key to an existing column, then that column needs to hold only unique values. In this case, the TRANSACTIONID column has duplicate values in it.
